# How to retain the value of database driven Drop Down List Box when you click Edit?

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day!

I would like to ask how can I retain the value of my drop down box when I edit it.

in my form

```
<tr>
<td><strong>*Die Type:</strong></td> 
<td>
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM idie_type_tbl" ;
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            echo'<select name="die_type"  class="textfield">';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['die_type_id'].'">' . $row['die_type'] . '</option>';   
            }
            echo '</select>';

        ?>
</td>
```

same also in my edit.php script. how can I retain the value of my database driven drop down box in edit.php

thanks..

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Lol you deleted your that question ...but make sure that you use pdo carefully ..see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the submitted value from `$_GET/POST`
2. While looping over the possible values, test to see if there is a match
3. Add a `selected` attribute if there is

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin said follow his instruction and use below code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
     if($_POST['die_type'] == $row['die_type_id']) {
         echo '<option value="'.$row['die_type_id'].'" selected = "selected">' . $row['die_type'] . '</option>'; 
     } else {
         echo '<option value="'.$row['die_type_id'].'">' . $row['die_type'] . '</option>';
     }  
}
```

Comment: @ChocoMartin which method you are using in your form? `GET` OR `POST`?

Comment: @ChocoMartin then it should work. Can you elaborate `still not OK` means?

Comment: I already changed my code and use your code. still not OK. I already use POST as method. when I click the edit, the first option still appear in the dropdown

Comment: @yoyesh how will I be able to get the value of submitted value from my post